Typescript не проверяет типы при использовании spread-оператора
Никак не могу разобраться, почему не работает проверка типов в следующем примере:
interface Props {
    readonly value: string;
}

const Component = ({ value }: Props) => {
    return <div>{value}</div>;
};

const otherProps = {
  id: 'test',
}

const a = <Component {...otherProps} value='test' />

Ожидаю, что ts будет ругаться, так как свойство id не существует в типе Props.

interface игнорирует «лишние» свойства, ругаться тут не на что

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks проверка «лишних» свойств работает только на литералах.

А можно как-то изменить код, чтобы проверка заработала?

А можно нескромный вопрос — зачем?

Разве это валидный typescript? Мне кажется, не хватает метки react...

Ну если я буду использовать этот компонент, то хотелось бы видеть, что он не поддерживает указанные свойства. Явная передача вызывает же ошибку. Хочу и в этому случае ее видеть. Т.е. сразу видеть, что компонент нуждается в доработке, например.

@AndreiKhotko, ну во-первых, тайпскрипт умеет jsx из коробки, во-вторых, jsx может быть не только реактом, а в-третьих, разве без jsx что-нибудь изменится?

@Qwertiy если без jsx ничего не изменится, значит нужно упростить минимальный воспроизводимый пример, выкинув из него jsx

@andreymal, а что, пример в вопросе сложный?

@Qwertiy не минимальный, сложность ни при чём

@andreymal, если что-то надо упростить, то оно сложное. А пример достаточно минимальный.

@Qwertiy я не рассматриваю вопросы с react меткой, т.к. не изучал его (соответственно, и jsx тоже). Тут я увидел вопрос с меткой typescript - пошел смотреть c надеждой, что смогу помочь. Зашел - увидел jsx - вышел.  Без знания jsx тут невозможно помочь

@AndreiKhotko, но значние jsx - это не знание реакта. Jsx встроен в тайпскрипт: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html. И без jsx этот пример можно заменить на такой - почти ничего не изменилось. Только нельзя функции лишние аргументы добавлять, хотя, не очень-то и хотелось.


А можно как-то изменить код, чтобы проверка заработала?

Можно, но тебе не понравится: песочница
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
    readonly value: string;
}

const Component = <P extends Props>({ value }: { [key in keyof P]: key extends keyof Props ? P[key] : never }) => {
    return <div>{value}</div>;
};

const otherProps = {
    id: 'test', 
}

const a = <Component value='test' />
const b = <Component {...otherProps} /> // Property 'value' is missing in type '{ id: string; }' but required in type '{ readonly value: string; }'
const c = <Component {...otherProps} value='test' /> // Type '{ value: "test"; id: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ value: "test"; id: never; }'

При желании можно вынести хэлперный тип, но компонент всё равно должен быть generic'омЖ песочница
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
    readonly value: string;
}

type Strict<P, B, R = { [key in keyof P]: key extends keyof B ? P[key] : never }> = R

const Component = <P extends Props>({ value }: Strict<P, Props>) => {
    return <div>{value}</div>;
};

const otherProps = {
    id: 'test', 
}

const a = <Component value='test' />
const b = <Component {...otherProps} />
const c = <Component {...otherProps} value='test' />

Я сделал R пораметром дженерика чтобы иметь более красивую ошибку несоответствия типов, хотя такая запись и позволяет натворить какую-то дичь передав третий параметр явно.

Спасибо за ответ. Решение, конечно, нетривиальное. И я до сих пор не понимаю, почему TS это не делает из коробки.

@Tokisoda потому что это сложно и ненужно. И будет банально врать потому что типы в TS структурные. Вот напишу otherProps = { value: 'test', id: 'test' } as Props; <Component {...otherProps} /> и вся ваша проверка ничего не скажет. А в реальном коде этот as Props спрятан за тремя слоями других компонентов.

@Tokisoda в общем гораздо правильнее писать код так что бы лишние свойства ничего не ломали. Даже в вашем оригинальном компоненте наличие лишнего id ни на что не влияет.

Спасибо за разъяснения!

@AlexeyTen, надо просто изначально делить питы на чистые и грязные - это бы вполне позволило легко сделать проверку. А что касается тог8о, ломает, или нет - если спред попадёт на dom-элеиент, то строки - ему в атрибуты, а не строки - разработчику в консоль - и даже если всё работает как задумано, всё равно всюду мусор...

@Qwertiy это надо было делать в TS 0.1, но тогда бы он не взлетел

@AlexeyTen, да в любой момент можно.
